# About clopen set in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: metric-spaces

Is there any clopen set in the metric space ($\mathbb R^n$,$d$) (where $d$ is the usual metric)

besides $\mathbb R^n$  & the empty set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. If there were such a set $U$, then setting $V = \mathbb{R}^n \setminus U$, $V$ will also be clopen, so that $\mathbb{R}^n = U \sqcup V$ is a decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a union of nonempty disjoint open sets.

Comment: How can I prove $U$ and $V$ are separated?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If U and V are separated and U $\union$ V =$\mathbb R^n$ then $\mathbb R^n$ is not connected

Comment: We defined $V$ so that it has nothing in common with $U$. (Also, the LaTeX command for the 'union' symbol is \cup !)

Answer (score 2):

The metric spaces $X$ for which the only clopen subsets are $\emptyset$ and $X$ have a name: connected spaces. And, yes, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is connected. Therefore, it has no other clopen subsets.

Comment: It's more general than metric spaces!

Comment: I know, but I suspect that the OP is not aware of topological spaces.

Comment: That's fair. I figured you did but wanted to add it in case OP does know about them.